# Why the AXI config registers are called GPV?

Tags: axi

GPV stands for "Global Programmers View". It appears in Xilinx/Intel/ARM documents related to AXI interconnect, e.g.,

- [intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683126/21-2/the-global-programmers-view.html)
- [ARM](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0397/f/CHDCBJBA)
- Xilinx: section 4.4 in UG585
- [STM32](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/group0/72/5f/0e/b5/f4/9f/46/76/STM32H7-System-Interconnect_Matrix_AXI/files/STM32H7-System-Interconnect_Matrix_AXI.pdf/_jcr_content/translations/en.STM32H7-System-Interconnect_Matrix_AXI.pdf)

The function of GPV, according to the STM32 link above, is "The AXI interconnect includes a global programmer view (GPV) which contains registers for configuring a few parameters, such as the quality of service (QoS) level ...".

The name looks strange to me. My question is, why this block of register is named as such?

- Global: vs. what kind of local stuff?
- Programmer: what kind of programmer?
- View: ?

I guess there might be some historical backgound for the name...

Thanks.

Comment: My idea: Imagine small boy staing at the CPU core and wathing to the wires to AXI controller. Global because it affects overal memory map how do the boy see it. Local point of view is AXI point of view which possibly see only subpart of the system address space and see it as ports rather as address space. "Programmer" is oppsition to hardware designer. GPV affect how firmware programmer (boy) see the memory map but do not influence physical hardware implementation. "View" comes from small boy watching memory bus approximation, I think.